# How to delete matching lines using sed in while loop

Tags: bash, awk, sed, while-loop

Below is the content of claim_note file

```
B|2050013344207770
B|2050013344157085
```

I have Input file which has values

```
B|2050013344207770|xxx|xxx 
B|2050013344157085|xxx|xxx
B|2050013344157999|xxx|xxx
```

I am using below code to delete matching line in Input file, but my code delete only first matching pattern

```
cat claim_note | while read FILE
do
echo $FILE
sed -n "/$FILE/!p" Input > TempInput
mv TempInput Input
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `grep`:

```
grep -vf claim.txt input.txt
```

Output:

```
B|2050013344157999|xxx|xxx
```

Comment: Hi, this command worked yesterday in cygwin but not in Putty. Could you pls help

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Also, what is the version of `grep --version` ?

Comment: Its simply not given any output, for eg if I give grep -e "2050013344157999" input.txt, it generates Output: B|2050013344157999|xxx|xxx But if I give grep -f claim.txt input.txt (only 2050013344157999 inside claim.txt), it doesnt print anything

Comment: @EdwinJoel, Did you try with `grep -vf` (**-v**).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping and using send on every line you can use `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]; next} !(($1,$2) in a)' claim_note Input

B|2050013344157999|xxx|xxx
```

Comment: Hi, this command worked yesterday in cygwin but not in Putty. Could you pls help

Comment: This command has no dependency on cygwin or putty. Eventually it is awk that runs it.